# In jQuery, how can I fadeOut an overlayed div by clicking anywhere in the body?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making an image viewer. When I click on an image, it fades in the "overlay" Div with the image inside. But with the code below, when I click on the image, the div fades in but it immediately fades out without me re-clicking. What is wrong with me code?

I believe I need to put that "body click" line *inside* the first function but it doesn't work. How can I make such that this "body click" happens only after the overlay fades in?

Thanks in advance.

```
$('.pic').click(function(){
        $('#overlay').html("<img class='enlarged_pic' src='" + (this).src + "'>").fadeIn();
        }); 

$('body').click(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to your first handler. What happens is that the click event is bubbling from your .pic up to the body, triggering both handlers when you only want one. `.stopPropagation()` blocks the event from bubbling any higher up the DOM.

```
$('.pic').click(function(e){ // don't forget that 'e'
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#overlay').html("<img class='enlarged_pic' src='" + (this).src + "'>").fadeIn();
}); 

$('body').click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VQkNa/

You may also want to make it so that clicking on the overlay itself doesn't fade the overlay. This is easily done by detecting the target of a click:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== "overlay") {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    };
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VQkNa/1/

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your response. Didn't know about this stopPropagation function. It did solve my problem in a very concise way. Thanks again. Regards

Comment: Had pretty much the same problem, finally found a great answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that both of your methods are being called.

When you click the '.pic' it calls the .fadeIn();
And also, because when you click '.pic' it is also on the body, it calls the .fadeOut();

I would try changing your selector on the body, to not include .pics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var isOverlaid = false;
$('.pic').mousedown(function() {
    $('#overlay').html("<img class='enlarged_pic' src='" + (this).src + "'>").fadeIn('slow', function() {
        isOverlaid = true;
    });

});
$('body').mousedown(function() {
    if (isOverlaid) {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            isOverlaid = false;
        });
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeNc8/

Comment: Hi there thanks for your response. It solved the problem. Alternatiely, user mblase75 found a shorter way using e.stopPropagation().
Thanks again, regards